# Getting error from realm : TypeError: _realm.default.open is not a function

Tags: react-native, realm

Getting error from realm after integrating on react native platform :

> TypeError: _realm.default.open is not a function

trying to connect with local realm db :

```js
const init = async () => {
  try {
    const realm = await Realm.open({
      path: "realm-files/myrealm",
      schema: [TaskSchema],
    });
    console.log("connection details", realm);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("I am an error", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: You've not indicated what line in your code is throwing the error so it's a bit difficult to troubleshoot. I would suggest that in `_realm.default.open` the `default` does not have an open function.